# Post-hook to DBT_CLOUD_PR Schemas (DBT Cloud CI)

Tags: database, continuous-integration, roles, snowflake-schema, dbt

I was wondering if it is possible to attach a post hook to DBT_CLOUD_PR Schemas (Generated by dbt Cloud CI) so that only the developers can see the PR tables generated on the database.

I would like to do something looking like the following:

```
dbt_cloud_pr:
  +post-hook:
    - "revoke select on {{ this }} from role reporter"
```

Right now, our dbt_cloud_pr schemas can be seen by multiple roles on Snowflake, and it clusters the database with some non-essential schemas that we would rather hide.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cool idea!

You can configure your dbt Cloud CI job to use a custom "target" name (it's the Job > Edit Settings page). Let's say you set that to `ci`

Then I think in your code you should be able to add a post-hook like

```
models:
  +post-hook: {% if target.name == 'ci' %} revoke select on {{ this }} from role reporter {% else %} select 1 {% endif %}
```

If that if..else syntax isn't allowed in the post-hook itself, you can wrap it in a macro, and call that macro from the post-hook:

```
models:
  +post-hook: {{ revoke_select_on_ci(this) }}
```

And in your macros directory:

```
{%- macro revoke_select_on_ci(model, ci_target='ci') -%}
    {%- if target.name == ci_target -%}
        revoke select on {{ model }} from role reporter
    {%- else -%}
        select 1
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endmacro -%}
```

Comment: Amazing thanks for your help ! I would correct one thing tho:
Change target to target.name (to properly return the name, but super job !)

Comment: You are totally right. Answer edited to reflect that